# Склонение фамилии Пидгаец

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Как правильно склоняется фамилия Пидгаец. Встречаются варианты:Пидгаецу и Пидгайцу. А женскую фамилию склонять нужно?

Answer (score 1):

В отношении мужских фамилий на -ец есть правило, что такие фамилии склоняются с беглой гласной (Пидгайца, Пидгайцу) если они славянского проихождения. Однако в том случае, если в формах склонения возникает неблагозвучие или трудности при восстановлении исходной формы, возможно склонение и без беглой гласной (Пидгаеца, Пидгаецу). 
В нашем случае таких затруднений, вроде бы не возникает, но тем не менее стоит при возможности проконсультироваться у конкретного носителя фамилии, как он предпочитает её склонять. 
Если же такой возможности нет, то я бы предпочел вариант с беглой гласной: Пидгайца, Пидгайцу, как эти имеет место в украинском.

Кстати, ссылки на необходимость единообразия, если они идут не от самих носителей, в данном случае не следует принимать всерьёз. Даже одинаковая фамилия у разных носителей может склоняться по разному.   
Женская фамилия, естественно, не склоняется.

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте! Женская фамилия не склоняется точно. А с мужской, думаю, что по аналогии с другими словами на -ец. Например, боец-бойца, китаец-китайца. Тогда Пидгайца